# Tier 5 UK visa financial evidence

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, immigration, student-visa

One of the requirements for a tier 5 UK visa is to have at least 945£ as savings for 3 months in the bank.Is it acceptable to put that sum in one deposit into the bank account? Or it should reflect salary savings? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must have had the 945£ in your bank account for 90 days before you apply, so if you make a lump sum payment like a month for example before submitting your application, I am not sure it would be acceptable.

Comment: Is it accepted to make a lump sum more than 3 months before applying ? Or the the money should reflect savings?